# How to read wtmp file?

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment that deals with using various data structures to store and sort data. The data structures portion is fairly straight forward to me, however, I am getting hung up on the first step, reading/parsing a wtmp file. I've parsed several files previously, but never have I parsed a binary file. What's the trick to parsing such a file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man 5 wtmp` describes the format of this file, but parsing the (textual) output of `last` may be easier than parsing it directly. I don't think there's an API in the standard C library to read `wtmp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [utmp.h](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_wtmp.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to go about parsing it, you need to read the bytes of the file into a utmp struct. You should really check the manual page for all the details, this is not the same as reading a file with the standard C library.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<utmp.h>

int main()
{
      int fd;
      struct utmp cr;
      int reclen = sizeof(struct utmp);

      fd = open(WTMP_FILE, O_RDONLY);
      if (fd == -1){
        perror("oops");
        exit(1);
      }
      while (read(fd, &cr, reclen) == reclen)
        printf("-- %s\n", cr.ut_user);

      close (fd);
      return 0;
}
```